# How to add columns to Relevant Documents Web Part?

Tags: column, folder, versioning, custom-field-types, out-of-the-box

The client has a custom aspx page that displays to users files that have not been checked in (marked by an icon), version number, user that the file is checked out to (marked out), Library location, folder location, file name and last modified date shown below.[image: Custom Page]

Client wants a web part that shows these files only to the current user signed in. I found Relevant Documents Web Part (OOTB) works fine. Problem is, I need assistance on how to add the icon, version number, and folder location columns. Can someone show or point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you not able to edit the aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Relevant Documents Web Part, you could you a List View Web Part and filter the list view for the current user. Then you could easily add/remove whatever columns you want from the list view.

To do this, edit the List View Web Part properties and then under `Selected View` click on `Edit the current view`. Under the `Filter` section, set the filter so that the `Created By` and `Modified By` columns equal `[Me]` like so:

[image: filter in web part]

Whenever a user views that web part, they will only see documents created by or modified by him/her.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The custom coded (named checkedOut.aspx) page pulls data from hundreds of libraries and displays all checked out files and to whom they're checked out to. I've looked into this and just wanted to ask if this is still possible with a List View Web Part?

Comment: no this is only for one list

Comment: @Heatguy2015 Thanks for the clarification about the page pulling data from multiple libraries -- you should probably add this additional info in your question as it will help people in thinking about solutions for you. As for the List View Web Part, this only works for 1 list, so this solution won't work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, could you not just add another list view and set it as a "Personal view", edit the view in your Library settings and then add that to the Web Part or wherever you want to place it?

Comment: Wait, sorry... that's a stupid answer... the personal view won't work. Back to the drawing board....

Comment: No worries! Any suggestions are helpful!